# tomcat manager in redhat enterprise linux (RHEL7)?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, rhel, rhel7

I want to use the `Tomcat Manager` web app ([link](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html)).  It is distributed by Apache (e.g. as part of their core `tar.gz` binary distribution in their [download page](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi)).  However it seems that the web app is not packaged in any one of the RPM packages offered by Redhat Enterprise Linux 7 (RHEL7).

```
tomcat-jsp-2.2-api.noarch : Apache Tomcat JSP API implementation classes
tomcat-lib.noarch : Libraries needed to run the Tomcat Web container
tomcat-servlet-3.0-api.noarch : Apache Tomcat Servlet API implementation classes
tomcat.noarch : Apache Servlet/JSP Engine, RI for Servlet 3.0/JSP 2.2 API
tomcat-el-2.2-api.noarch : Expression Language v2.2 API
```

Is that true?  (And Why?)

Does that mean we will have to package our own RPM if we want to use the web app and get it deployed via RPM?

We are using RHEL 7.3 and Tomcat 7.0.69

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the RHEL docs here:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Package_Manifest/chap-Base-Server-Variant.html

The server variant of RHEL 7 lists tomcat-webapps (installs the tomcat root page) and tomcat-admin-webapps (installs the web application manager and virtual host manager) as core packages. I would check for those packages specifically.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Indeed on the page I saw the mentioning of `tomcat-admin-webapps`, which is encouraging.  On the site I could not find a way to examine the content of this RPM, but then when I googled for `tomcat-admin-webapps` I find another RPMfind.net is listing the contents: http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/epel/6/x86_64/tomcat-admin-webapps-7.0.73-1.el6.noarch.html